# Does the Dark Apprentice exist at the same time as Starkiller?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, video-games

### Spoilers from *The Force Unleashed II*

> In an ending for *The Force Unleashed II*, if the player was to chose the Dark Side (i.e. to kill Vader), we learn that the protagonist (i.e. Starkiller) was actually not the sole successful clone of Galen Marek. We meet the Dark Apprentice:

[image]

> He decloaks behind Starkiller, stabs him, kills Kota and Juno Eclipse, and goes on to exterminate rebel scums across the Galaxy.

Question is, does the Dark Apprentice exist in the Light Side ending as well? I mean, does the Dark Apprentice exist throughout the course of the game, hiding, and *only* reveals himself if the player chose the Dark Side? Or does the Dark Apprentice only come in play (out-of-universe) to fill the place of a Dark Side protagonist for further installments?

Comment: As a side note, do we have tags for *The Force Unleashed* games, and Starkiller in particular?

Comment: Um...doesn't your question answer itself?  The character appears and kills the PC (thanks for the spoiler, BTW) before running off.  This implies that they exist at the same time.  If they exist at the same time in that ending, they must presumably exist in all endings, since that ending (to my knowledge) doesn't involve any time-travel shenanigans that would be responsible for the DA's existence.

Comment: @Jeff  -  but that is only the Dark side ending. I wonder if the Dark guy exists in the Light-side ending as well, i.e. if he existed throughout the game, without us knowing. Btw, sorry for the spoiler!

Comment: If he exists in one ending - and that ending didn't have any indication that the player's choices which created that ending also created the character - it stands to reason that he exists in all endings.  There really isn't any other way to answer this, short of word from the script writer and/or game developer.

Comment: @Jeff one ending may be cannon and the other non-cannon (or both non-cannon); this would mean that what happens in one of them does not need to be consistent with the other.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING: Spoilers.

> The Dark Apprentice does exists in the light side ending. This is proven in extra cut-scene  called “Distant Thunder”: it shows Vader training him and showing him the corpse of the original Galen Marek, proving that both he and the “Starkiller” you play as are both clones. The Dark Apprentice then kills a holodroid in the form of Juno Eclipse.

.

> Finally, when “Starkiller” attacks Kamino, Vader orders him to stay hidden (by using the force to become invisible) and not to intervene until his assistance was absolutely required. However, as you know, “Starkiller” refuses to kill Vader and so the Dark Apprentice doesn’t kill him.

.

> However he is still right there in the light side ending (obviously you can’t see him) but he presumably heals Juno and definitely is on the Rogue Shadow at the end. More than this I cannot say.

Comment: Do you have a link to said cutscene and anything that shows or even hint that he is there, hidden somewhere, during the Light Side ending?